Lavaan exploratory factor analysis: model may not be identified warning
I am running an exploratory factor analysis in lavaan and the 2-factor model produces the following warning:
Warning: lavaan->lav_model_vcov():
The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov) does not appear to be positive definite! The
smallest eigenvalue (= 4.683198e-20) is close to zero. This may be a symptom that the model is not identified.
Here is my code for the factor analysis:
fit2 <- efa(data = scaled_FA.df, nfactors = 2, rotation= 'oblimin', missing='pairwise')
summary(fit2)

The factor analysis is based on participant (n=73) task data including 10 variables.
I realise that this is a small sample size: is this the reason for this issue? How can I assess whether my results are reliable? During parallel analysis, I noticed there were some negative eigenvalues: I am not sure whether this is relevant here?
This question has been asked before but I did not understand the response and/or the suggested code in the response did not work for me. I am new to factor analysis so would appreciate a response in as simple terms as possible!
